# Pulling out a dictionary field to use as a function name

Tags: python, function, dictionary, user-defined-functions, python-3.7

I am attempting to create functions using a for loop, by referencing a dictionary.

My two different attempts have been unsuccessful:

```
dictionary = {1:'Apples', 2:'Pears', 3:'Carrots'}

for i in range(1, 4, 1):
    name = dictionary[i]
    def name(price, quantity):
        total = price*quantity
        return total

print(Apples(3, 2))
```

This method was unsuccessful as 'name' becomes the function name that is being defined. (*NameError*)

```
for i in range(1, 4, 1):
    def dictionary[i](price, quantity):
        total = price*quantity
        return total
```

This method was unsuccessful as having square brackets when defining a function is considered a syntax error.

Is there a way I can pull the name of a field in the dictionary to make it a function?

Comment: Why would you need to do this? What's the point of 4 identical functions with different names?

Comment: I am simplifying the situation in order to receive as clear an answer as possible, in reference to my real issue, I will be using this solution to create multiple pages in Tkinter, which use different names but that are all inherently the same.

Comment: You're aware that dictionary values can be functions, right? In other words, there may be no reason to store the function's name in the dictionary.

Comment: @martineau Please elaborate, I do not follow your meaning as what I am trying to do in the question is using a dictionary value in a function. IE  `def dictionary[i]` = `def apples`

Comment: @Matt: I meant a `dict` can map keys to (pre-existing) functions. e.g. if you have a defined function named `my_func()`, you could create a dictionary containing `{'Plums': my_func}`. In fact, you even associate it with another key (either in the same or a different dict), i.e. `{'Plums': my_func, 'Prunes': my_func}`. The function could then be called either via `dictionary['Plums']()` or `dictionary['Prunes']()`. For a more concrete answer, post another question. Note I suspect this might be what is called an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
for i in range(1, 4, 1):
    name = dictionary[i]
    def _fn(price, quantity):
        total = price*quantity
        return total
    globals()[name] = _fn
```

but it's pretty uncommon to need to do this.

A more sensible way to do this (as @martineau describes), is to put the functions directly in the dict:

```
def Apples(price, quantity):
    total = price * quantity
    return total

def Pears(...): ...
def Carrots(...): ...

dictionary = {1: Apples, 2: Pears, 3: Carrots}
```

you would call the functions like:

```
dictionary[1](price=2.50, quantity=4)
```

if you rename `dictionary` to `total` it can be quite readable:

```
product_id = 1
total_price = total[product_id](price=2.50, quantity=4)
```

if all the functions are the same it's even easier:

```
def totalfn(price, quantity):
    total = price * quantity
    return total

total = {1: totalfn, 2: totalfn, 3: totalfn}
```

or even shorter if you have many products:

```
total = {productid: totalfn for productid in (1,2,3)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are essentially copying a function into multiple ones with different names, and verify this in your comment "use different names but that are all inherently the same", I think the easiest way would be to define your base function first, and copy it to however many different new functions you want. Like this:

Your base function is always returning `price*quantity`, so let's define it:

```
def base_fun(price, quantity):
    total = price*quantity
    return total
```

Now let's clone this into your dictionary items:

```
import copy

for k, v in dictionary.items():
  globals()[v] = copy.copy(base_fun)

print(Apples(3, 2)) #returns 6
print(Pears(5, 4)) #returns 20
print(Pears(0, 3)) #returns 0
```